# Regex that picks up content in between

Tags: php, regex

In a large HTML document, I have multiple lines that look like this. The value 'TEST' can be different. I want to pick up `TEST` or whatever else is in its place.

`<TD width=300 valign=top><FONT COLOR=800000 size=3>TEST</FONT><BR>`

I have this regex:

```
$regex = "/<FONT COLOR=800000 size=3>[\w.&,\s]*<\/FONT>/";
```

It picks up all the lines that look like the one I posted above. How can I, instead of the entire line, pick up only TEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$regex = "/<FONT COLOR=800000 size=3>([\w.&,\s]*)<\/FONT>/";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
```

you will have all matches in `$matches` array, `$matches[1]` should be your "TEST".

Comment: and if I want to use `preg_match_all`?

Comment: just you `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`, rest is the same .. you can see the contents of `$matches` by printing it for example with `print_r($matches)` or `var_dump($matches)`

Comment: `preg_match_all` will give `$matches` in the same format as `preg_match`, but wrapped in an additional array (since it returns multiple results). So you can access your TEST with `$matches[$i][1]`, for `0 <= $i < count($matches)`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, [obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/240443).

If you really want to regexp it, put parentheses around `[\w.&, ]*]` and capture the content into a group, then read off the group instead of the whole match. **EDIT** I see @boobiq shows you how exactly to do this, so I'm not gonna. :p

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html), thus changing your regex to this:

```
"/<FONT COLOR=800000 size=3>([\w.&, ]*)<\/FONT>/"
```

The round brackets denote groups.

Ideally you should never parse HTML with regex ([why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))... you should use a framework like the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I was staying away from DOM parsers since I didn't want to make the assumption of valid HTML. However, your link says it supports invalid HTMl as well. I'll definitely have a look at it.

Comment: I'm loving the DOM Parser! Ditched regex for it.

Comment: @xbonez: Then why not select this as the answer?